# Parity build error

Tags: parity

mac os 10.14.4

CMake-3.14.4 was installed by running the bootstrap script in CMake-3.14.4 directory.

then ran

```
$ git clone https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum

$ cd parity-ethereum

$ cargo build --release --features final
```

I received the following output:

> error: failed to run custom build command for `parity-snappy-sys
>   v0.1.2` process didn't exit successfully:
>   `/Users/nancyibsen/parity-ethereum/target/release/build/parity-snappy-sys-d4afabb3fc9ca272/build-script-build`
>   (exit code: 101)
>   --- stdout running: "cmake" "/Users/nancyibsen/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parity-snappy-sys-0.1.2/snappy"
>   "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON"
>   "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/nancyibsen/parity-ethereum/target/release/build/parity-snappy-sys-8457319861bfa2d8/out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64"
>   "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=
>   -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
>
> --- stderr thread 'main' panicked at ' failed to execute command: No such file or directory (os error 2) is `cmake` not installed?
>
> build script failed, must exit now',
>   /Users/nancyibsen/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cmake-0.1.35/src/lib.rs:778:5
>   note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a
>   backtrace.
>
> warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish... error:
>   build failed

Can anyone please point to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I got it to work. I had to install cmake with brew.

Comment: i have the same problems as yours and i already have cmake installed, can you help me, thanks